# who pass parameters to Grails index action

Tags: grails

I can't understand how the auto-generated index action works :

```
def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond TekEvent.list(params), model:[tekEventCount: TekEvent.count()]
    }
```

Who will passe "max" to the  index method?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some auto-generated views, and the answer will become more apparent.

You don't have to pass the index method a max value, it will default to a value if you don't, and proceed.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question :/ I asked elsewhere and they gave me theses links :  
Data Binding And Action Arguments" sub-section at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.5/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding  
and the Command Object notes at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.5/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects